# KVM Switch for 2 monitors and 4 computers

Tags: kvm

Most of the details are in the title.  DP into the switch and DP out.  I don't care about USB 2.0 or 3.0, it's just a mouse and keyboard.  There are a ton on Amazon, but from brands that I'd never recognize.  Budget: < $500